# Angular 7 FormControl cast input from number to string

Tags: forms, angular7, angular-forms

I have a FormGroup where I defined a FormControl used this way:

```
myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({ 
    ...
    code: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')),
    ...
  });
```

html:

```
<mat-form-field class="col">
                <input formControlName="code" matInput>
              </mat-form-field>
```

I want this input to be a number, but I can't cast it correctly. I've registered to the `vauleChanges` event of the form control and did this:

```
this.myForm.controls['code'].valueChanges.subscribe(d => {
     if(this.myForm.controls['code'].valid){
      this.myForm.get('code').setValue( +this.myForm.controls['code'].value);
      }
    })
```

I've also tried using `as number` or `<number>` to cast the value, but if I print the value of my form I get it printed as a string and not a number.
Also, my input shows 0 as default when I load the page:
[image]

but I didn't set 0 anywhere and I don't want it to be showing.
I've tried specifying the input type as number, but it shows the arrows and I don't want them to show.

[image]

What is the correct way to implement this? I'm a lot confused.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

You could simply check for changes in model *(ngModelChange)="validate()"* check for *validate()* method.

**HTML FILE:**

```
<input id="code" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="code" required (ngModelChange)="validate()">

<div *ngIf="codeValidator.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div *ngIf="codeValidator.errors.required">
        Field must not be empty.
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="codeValidator.errors.pattern">
        Only numeric values are allowed.
    </div>
</div>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="numberValue">
```

**TS FILE:**

```
  code = 0;
  codeValidator: any = {};
  numberValue: any;


  validate() {
    console.log("Validating");
    this.codeValidator = new FormControl(this.code, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')
    ]);
    // You could simply use isNaN
    this.numberValue = isNaN(this.code) || this.code === 0 ? '' : +this.code;
  }
```